# Unable to 'Get Data' from folder in Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, macos, powerquery

I am trying to introduce Power Query into some processes. Currently, I am working on a MacBook, which apparently poses some difficulties with Power Query.

I am able to import Excel- and CSV-files with no issues. However, for the task at hand, I need to get data from multiple files in a folder.

Can it really be true that this is not possible to do on Excel for Mac?

Can the data be imported e.g., in Google Sheets and then exported to an .xlsx file?

Comment: Re your 'can it really be true' question: yes. The ability to *create* any Power Queries has only just been introduced on the Mac.

Comment: Alright, thank you! Saved me tons of research time. Hopefully it will be introduced soon.

Comment: I don't know if this will help as I've never done it, but you might be able to author the Query in Windows Excel using VBA, then transfer it to the Mac.  See [Import data in Excel for Mac (Power Query)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-in-excel-for-mac-power-query-7b2f337d-e7d2-4fdf-bf00-3dfbb1e5e9c5) `=>Author and transfer Power Query VBA code`